# Index of stationarity of a time domain signal

Tags: time-series, time-domain

During my internship, I've come across a software that calculates a percentage called "Index of stationarity". This index shows how much stationary is the signal. Does anyone have any idea on how to assess the stationarity of a signal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This a very complicated question, and I would say a still open topic. The concept of stationarity is manifold, from pure statistics to applied DSP (strict, strong, wide-sense, quasi-stationarity, cyclo-stationarity, to refer to a recently closed question). The lack of access to sound models and faithful realizations renders the quest quite difficult.

Non-stationary is a non-property (like non-linearity, non-causality). Refocusing on some breeds may help its characterization, whether  you are interested in:

- randomly stepping piece-wise constant signals
- "sines" of  varying frequency (like chirps)
- stochastic data of changing distribution
- etc.

Yet, a common framework resides in using time-frequency representations, assuming some local stationarity and trying to assess the non-stationarity according to some metric/distance/divergence (norms, Kolmogorov, Kullback, Jensen, etc.) over the time. Here are two possible (first) references:

- [Stationary index for abrupt changes detection in the time-frequency plane](https://doi.org/10.1109/97.659547), 1998
- [Testing Stationarity With Surrogates: A Time-Frequency Approach](https://doi.org/10.1109/TSP.2010.2043971), 2010